# Problem regarding concept of weightlessness

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, centripetal-force, centrifugal-force

> A simple pendulum having a bob of mass m is suspended from the ceiling of a car used in a stunt film shooting. The car moves up along an inclined cliff at a speed v and makes a jump to leave the cliff and lands at some distance. Let R be the maximum height of the car from the top of the cliff. Tension in the pendulum's string when the car is in the air is
>
> A) mg
>
> B) mg-mv²/R
>
> C) mg + mv²/R
>
> D) zero
>
> The answer given is D) zero

I tried to analyze the bob with respect to the frame of the car which is obviously non inertial.At the max height, we have to apply a pseudo force (centrifugal) mg upwards on the bob which balances gravitational force (mg downwards) on the bob. But i dont know what that says about the tension in the string. Is this the right approach, can someone help me out.These similar type of problems where a pseudo force balances gravity in a non inertial frame confuse me many times. Can someone give a clear solution as to why tension will be zero?

Comment: The given answer (and both the posts below) are working from the assumption that the bob is at rest with respect to the car when the pair go into free-fall. I suspect that this would be rather difficult to achieve in practice, but under those conditions they are entirely correct.

Answer (score 0):

Why is there tension in the first place, i.e. when the car is standing on the ground? The gravitational force of the bob of mass m is responsible for this. The bob is hanging from the ceiling without movement because the gravitational force is compensated by the tension in the string. There is a net force of 0 N.

If you now have a different force which completely compensates the gravitational force acting on the bob, the string will not be tense. It does not move either if there is an exact balance of the forces but no more tension is required to hold the bob in place.

Now for your understanding, consider this every-day example: If you drive in your car and you pass a curve. You will feel a pull towards one side. This is because inertia wants to keep you moving in the direction you moved before whereas your car (and the seat belt holding you) is steering in a different direction. However, it feels like something is pulling you to the side. This is the so-called pseudo force.
Those forces are real but depending on the frame from which you look at them, they appear to be different. Same with the pendulum, it's called a pseudo-force but there is a very real force acting on your pendulum. I strongly suggest reading the [wiki article on weightlessness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weightlessness) ;)

Comment: Yes I very well understand the concept of pseudo force. Assume the same pendulum is attached to the ceiling of an elevator. Assume to elevator is allowed to free fall. Now before it was allowed to free fall T=mg. When the elevator is falling freely is we analyse the bob in the elevator frame - the pseudo force (mg) balances the gravitational force mg. But i dont understand why tension which just a second ago was mg now becomes 0?

Comment: But if i analyse the bob with respect to an inertial frame knowing that under free fall it will be falling down with acceleration g, I can write mg-T=mg which gives T=0.

Comment: So when we analyse bodies in non inertial frames like the above example i gave, does it effectively translate to "switching gravity off meaning g=0" which then makes sense as T which was mg becomes 0 as g=0????

Comment: Ok, concerning your first comment: The reason the tension changes from one second to another is that the elevator is allowed to fall freely from one second to another. It should not be surprising because this changes the forces quite a bit. If you look at the bob in the falling elevator from the outside, the tension will also be zero. You just have 2 objects (elevator and bob) which are falling in the same way. But you don't experience this once you're inside the elevator which is why you use pseudo-forces to describe the effect.

Comment: You are most certainly not switching gravity off but in your example the whole frame of reference is moving due to gravity. So when another object is following gravity (bob), it just follows the frame of reference. The elevator and the falling bob will move in the same identical way and when you are part of that system, you yourself will be moving that way which is why you feel like there is no gravity.

Answer (score 0):

While the bob and the car are in free fall, there is no force between them, and the string's tension is necessarily zero...